# Urllib3 Python3, Getting Error No host specified, but the url works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I am trying to write images to database from excel sheet. I have this function to download images.

```
def downloadImage(url, Name):
    try:
        http    = urllib3.PoolManager()
        image   = http.request("GET", url, preload_content=False).data

    with File(open(f'{Name}-{timezone.now()}.jpg', 'wb')) as handler:
        handler.write(image)
    with handler.open(mode='rb') as nana:
        pass
except Exception as e:
    raise ValueError(e)
return handler
```

This is one of the url:

`https://i.imgur.com/BWomMaV.jpg`, When I print the url, it is similar coz I have seen posts where http/https is not added, but here the url works fine.

Can anyone tell me where the issue is?

This is how the function is called

```
Image(obj=instances[i], images=downloadImage(user['image1'], user['name']).open(mode='rb'))
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an error trace ?

Comment: Actually, this is the only error.